# New to Python and using Flask, my POST method isn't rendering in my local environment, getting a 302 Http status response

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm doing a flask tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA&t=1517s), and I can't get my app to show new to do's in the list when I post them to the database. There's no error, but I'm getting a 302 http response. My code is the same to the tutorial, so I am having trouble figuring out where the error is coming from. I believe the task is not actually getting posted to the database properly, but I'm not sure I know enough about Python to confirm.

**In app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_content = request.form['content']
        new_task = Todo(content=task_content)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_task)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'There was an issue adding your task'

    else:
        tasks = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.date_created).all()
        return render_template('index.html', task=tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run
```

**In index.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="content">
<h1>Task Master</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Added</th>
        <th>Actions</th>

    </tr>
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ task.content }} </td>
        <td>{{ task.date_created.date }} </td>
        <td>
            <a href="">delete</a>
            <br>
            <a href="">update</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="content" id="content">
    <input type="submit" value="Add Task">
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected with the line "return redirect('/')".

It seems quite useless to redirect the User to the '/' Page after the POST, where the browser will then call the GET Request to this same page.

You could do the following to skip the redirect and hence the HTTP 302.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_content = request.form['content']
        new_task = Todo(content=task_content)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_task)
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            return 'There was an issue adding your task'

    tasks = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.date_created).all()
    return render_template('index.html', task=tasks)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I used the code above and now I am getting a TypeError. It looks like I need to return something in the **try** statement

Comment: @ejbee3 I assume you only deleted the redirect an now you are not returning anything to the user - hence the TypeError. Please look again at the code example i posted, where i modified the „if“ branch as well, to always return something.

Comment: yeah it's still giving me a type error. I still need to return something in the try statement. I think I have to redirect somewhere after committing to the db session.